# Display server screen on clients screens

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-server-2012

i have a classroom with one server and 15 clients, and i want to display the content of my screen on the screens of these clients, is it possible ? and how to do it ?
PS: i have windows server 2012 on my server

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Set up a VNC server on the server machine and have the clients connect.

This would not work very well for movies and videos, however.